# Unable to retrieve data from a database query in a shiny markdown report

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I am trying to visualize some data in a rendered ggplot based on different inputs. Basically I have create a shiny markdown report:

```
---
title: "test"
author: ""
date: "6/4/2020"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---
```

```r
{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```r
{r include=FALSE}
library(lubridate)
library(odbc)
library(DBI)
library(ConfigParser)
library(aws.s3)
library(tidyverse)
library(tictoc)
library(imputeTS)
library(purrr)
library(furrr)

directory <- getwd()
source(paste("functions1.R", sep = ""))
source(paste("functions2.R", sep = ""))
source(paste("functions3.R", sep = ""))
source(paste("functions4.R", sep = ""))
config <- read.ini(paste("Parms.ini", sep = ""))
myconn <- myconfunction(environment = "DEV", 
                                       key_directory = config$PARM1$KEYDIR)
```

```r
{r include=FALSE}
df <- dbGetQuery(myconn, "querytogettheinputlist") %>% 
  rename_all(tolower)
```

```r
{r eruptions, echo=FALSE}
inputPanel(
  selectInput(inputId = "input1", label = "Input1",
              choices = as.character(df$col1), selected = as.character(df$col1[1])),
    selectInput(inputId = "frequency", label = "Frequency",
              choices = c("HOUR", "DAY", "WEEK", "MONTH"), selected = "HOUR")
  # dateRangeInput(inputId = "time_rage", label = "Date Range", start = "2018-01-01", end = "2019-01-01", 
  #                format = "yyyy-mm-dd", startview = "month",
  # weekstart = 0, language = "en", separator = " to ", width = NULL,
  # autoclose = TRUE)

)
 renderTable({dbGetQuery(OperEx.STARMS_DEV, paste("SELECT * FROM XXX
                                             WHERE variable1='", 
                                             input$input1, 
                                             "' AND EXTRACT(", 
                                             input$frequency, 
                                             " FROM SNSR_TS)=1")) %>% rename_all(tolower)})
})
```

However I can not see the result of this table (I can see the colnames but not the content):

[image]

Comment: Does your `dbgetQuery` actually return any data?  That would be a good place to start.

Comment: Yes it was,

My query returns data outside the markdown report.

BR

Answer (score 0):

Yes it was,

My query returns data outside the markdown report.

BR